# Why was Noah specifically required to build an ark with Gopher wood?

Tags: genesis, word-study, symbolism, noah, etymology

Genesis 6:14

> " Make yourself an ark of **gopherwood**; make rooms in the ark, and
>   cover it inside and outside with pitch.

There were different kinds of wood that could have served this purpose but God was specific about Gopher wood.

1) what kind of properties did the Gopher wood possess that would have caused it to be preferred for the salvation of eight souls from a flood.

2) Is there anything that this particular wood symbolises either through the etymology of its name or from other sources?

Comment: 'Gopher' wood is not a botanical category. It is from _gopthrith_ which is pitch. But 'gopher' wood is wood steeped in pitch so that it is waterproof.

Comment: @NigelJ. what language is "gopthrith"? English? Hebrew?

Comment: @NigelJ can you support your claim that the root of Gopher is Gophrith?

Comment: My apologies/spelling wrong from memory/ _gophrith_ is brimstone (Young's Concordance). But it is the sulphur content that is important. I understand it to mean 'molten' whether lava (volcanic) or pitch (the result of volcanic activity). 'Molten' with high sulphur content is a matter of judgment.

Comment: @NigelJ Gophrith actually means brimstone, something like that. But the phrase Gophrith is more of a derivative of gopher rather than the other way round.  So why would they be required to make an ark out of brimstone when the world was being Judged by water and not fire. Brimstone is used in the final judgment which is eternal and unending. So that's what the question is centered on.

Comment: @user20490 The wood was steeped in pitch which contains sulphur (brimstone). Once saturated with pitch internally it was then lathered externally. 'Kaphar the gopher with kopher' is the wording. All of this is figurative concerning judgment and containment. The eight souls were preserved through judgment within a containment,

Comment: @NigelJ That's a strong point you've made. I'm about to answer the question myself. The word "cover with pitch"=Kaphar in hebrew which means "Atonement". So the pitch was an antitype for the blood that covers sin and spares men from judgement. The pitch was actually blood in a symbolic sense.

Comment: @user20490  No, I don't think so. Kaphar/kopher is a matter of containment. Kaph is the cupped hand. Contained in the hand of God is the concept. The wood has already passed through judgement (brimstone). Thus the occupants are safe.

Comment: @user20490 See the linked PDF file from my website for my study of kaphar/kippurim. If you are interested. https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxiZWxtb250cHVibGljYXRpb25zfGd4OjdiYjBjYWZiZDA1OTA1YzI

Comment: @user20490 And then there is the amber (three times in Ezekiel). Amber is found in coal and coal is the result of wood being crushed at high pressure during the Flood, in sediments. And it often contains insects which are pre-Flood. Preserved in the resin of wood. Through judgement. And the colour of amber is associated with the cherubim.

Comment: @NigelJ  thanks for the link. At least I'll learn something new today.

Comment: @user20490 Glad to be of service.

Comment: Gopher wood = Redwood. The ark was a barge made from a single tree. Actually it was 3 barges

Answer (score 2):

"Gopher" in the KJV is simply a transcription of Hebrew גפר. There is no agreement among specialists as to what it means. It occurs only once in the Bible.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the IVP Bible Background Commentary has to say on "Gopher"

> Gopher is the Hebrew word translated “cypress wood” in the NIV. This
>   is an unknown type of material, although it undoubtedly refers to some
>   sort of coniferous tree thought to possess great strength and
>   durability. Cypress was often used by shipbuilders in the ancient Near
>   East. Similarly, the cedars of Lebanon were prized by the Egyptians
>   for the construction of their barques for transport on the Nile, for
>   instance in the eleventh century B.C. Diary of *Wenamon.

Answer (score 0):

In this verse (Gen 6:14), three terms (גפר, כפר [first time], and כפר [second time]) are interconnected by a single root. They are translated, commonly, with ‘gopher (wood)’, ‘pitch (it)’, and ‘tar’ (or, ‘pitch’, again), respectively.
    All of these term have in common the basic ‘**to cover**’-centered concept (Davidson, *Analytical Hebrew and Chaldee Lexicon*: “Gen 6. 14 גפר” i[d]. q[uod]. כפר, ‘to cover over’).
    From the latter variant כפר (through a consonantal commutation G  > K) - with a very good chance - were derived the Greek term **κυπάρισσος** (cypress) and, consequently, from here, the posterior (?) Latin term **cupressus**, of identical meaning.

```
“ […] *The ἁπ. λεγ. gopher is related to כֹּפֵר, resin, and κυπάρισσος; it is no proof to the contrary that in later Hebrew the cypress is called ‘berosh’, for ‘gopher’ belongs to the pre-Hebraic times*.” (Keil&Delitzsch, *Commentary on the Old Testament*)

“[…] *the cypress tree bids fairest to be the wood of which, the ark was made, as Fuller (Miscellan. Sacr. l. 4. c. 5.), Bochart (Phaleg. l. 1. c. 4. col. 22, 23), and others (id. Scheuchzer. Physic. Sacr. vol. 1. p. 35.) have shown; that being nearest to ‘Gopher’ in sound, and being a wood very durable and incorruptible, and fit for shipping. Alexander made a navy of cypress trees in the groves and gardens about Babylon, as Strabo (Geograph, l. 16. p. 510) relates* […]” (John Gill)

Salvatore Garofalo, *La Sacra Bibbia - Antico Testamento - Genesi* (the translation from Italian is mine): “[…] *Bochart glimpses in* [גפר] *the same root of the Greek [term] κυπάρισσος, ‘cypress’. Its wood were used by Phoenicians to build ships, and by Egyptians to make sarcophagus (= akk[adian] giparru)*.”

Jamieson, Fausset & Brown, *Commentary*: “[…] *probably cypress, remarkable for its durability and abounding on the Armenian mountains*.”
```

To answer your Question # 1, take account that the wood of cypress possesses **two main characteristics**:
a) it possesses an high stamina to immersions into sea water, since it is naturally impregnated with resin (כֹּפֵר);
b) it is woodworm-proof.

To answer your Question # 2, read, please the following information.

```
If we accept the abovementioned equivalence גפר = ‘cypress’ we will able to build a remarkable LOGICAL CIRCLE:
```

1 - **The Noah’s Ark** (made to resist to the Flood’s rains) **was made of cypress**.

2 - **The cypress**, taken as symbolic object, has - at all times - r**epresented death, or mourning from the dead ones**, and until today they are decking thousands of graveyards (artofmourning.com asserts: “C*upressus sempervirens, or the ‘Graveyard Cypress’ is one of the oldest classical mourning symbols used in Western and Eastern societies* [also in Muslim world] […]. K*nown as the ‘mournful tree’ by the Greeks and the Romans, the tree was sacred to the Fates and Furies as well as the rulers of the underworld* [like Pluto, the classical ruler of the underworld (see, for example the entry ‘Cyprès’ in the Dictionnaire des Symboles, by Jean Chevalier and Alain Gheerbrant)]. […] *Here, there is a great continuity of usage for the tree, as despite its cultural interchange it still remains understood for the same purposes in death*.”).

3 - **The very important Holiday for the Dead, related strictly to the All Saints’ Day/Halloween, falls on the identical year period of the start of Flood’s rains** (some reference works: *The Worship of the Dead*, by J. Garnier, 1904, London, e.g. Chapt. 1 pages 3-11; along with the following WEBlink htpps://aroyking.wordpress.com/2009/10/31/the-connection-between-halloween-and-the-great-flood/)

“*Come away, come away, death,
And in sad cypress let me be laid*.”

(William Shakespeare, *The Twelfth Night*, Act 2, Scene 4)

So, the wheel has come…

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to find out what Greek word that the 72 Jewish scholars chose for this word for the Septuagint.

The word they chose is *tetragonos* (τετράγωνος) or "four-cornered," which gave rise to speculation that this might actually be some early form of laminate or cross-grained plywood sheets. The same word, is used 14 times in the Bible. The last time it's used is in Revelation 21:16 "and the city four-cornered lies".

I would speculate that the original word might have sounded like the name of an antediluvian town or locale. I don't think we'll ever know for sure.

Dieter

Comment: It can also be argued that *tetragonos* refers to squared-off beams of wood, but it raises the question of whether the ark might otherwise have been built like a log cabin, which would be silly.

Answer (score 0):

The wood  is call golnopher  letter lno is missing in the word  gopher wood  it is s special wood  we local  people build our canoes  its our local language  same as the word Maria  the bitter water that Moses  touch and make it sweet Maria means ginger bitter and other word is mana bread from heaven  its our local language for food  call manang na na mising  there are plenty words  but i give only  few
Contact  for more information

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics.  Please take our Tour to find out what we look for in well-researched answers: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Welcome, Kambang kalu. From what little you have written, I detect some knowledge that is well worth sharing, but your lack of punctuation makes your comments very hard to understand. If you could use full stops and commas, then you answer would be interesting. Also, I wonder if the word for 'bitter water' in Moses' account is 'mara', and not the female name, 'Maria'?  Do polish your answer up a bit!